# Angular test case for ngIf when property value comes from @Input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to write testcase for @Input property. And check whether some value is present using ngIf directive within ng-container. So how to write test for such scenerio.

Here is my code. Please help me.

**ChildComponent.ts**

```
@Input() myInput;
```

**ChildComponent.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myInput?.value1">
- Display some code
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="myInput?.value2">
- Display some code
</ng-container>
```

In this code, How can we check if these ngIfs actually works. I really need little clue here in writing test case. Since Angular is new to me.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You must test the actual DOM which is rendered. You can use `DebugElement` to make DOM queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify presence of html elements within your test fixture in your angular tests, in your test do something like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should be present if color is blue', () => {
    component.color = 'blue';
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#elementThatIsPresentIfBlue')).not.toBeNull();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This solution really helped me in last min

Answer (score 0):

The @input variable i:e myInput is set from the host component. In order to check the rendering of specific `html` you can simulate the parent setting the input property.

In your test file, you can easily access the @Input variable using `[componentInstance.myInput]` and after changing the input value, you can check the rendering of conditional `html` element.

```
// In your test block

component.myInput = {value1: 'Val', value2: undefined};

// trigger manual data binding
fixture.detectChanges();

let firstEle = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector(`selector`);

expect(firstEle).toBeTruthy();

component.myInput = {value1: undefined, value2: 'val'};

// trigger manual data binding
fixture.detectChanges();

let secondEle = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector(`selector`);

expect(secondEle ).toBeTruthy();
```

***References***
https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-with-inputs-and-outputs

https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-basics#debugelement

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This solution really helped me in last min